# Galaxy S Duos 2 - No OS installed currently

Tags: cyanogenmod, custom-roms

Well I started with CWM to get Cyanogenmod 12 but all I did was remove any OS present.Now no OS is currently installed, and I cannot install any ROM as any installation fails with error 7. I tried to fix it with many possible solutions, none of which worked.

1. deleting `assert`,
2. updating binary file for patch,
3. replacing `set_metadata` with `set_perm`.

Now what to do? It will be great to get the stock ROM back.

Comment: Try ODIN-flashing the stock ROM

Answer (score 1):

You could try installing a factory firmware through ODIN. You can find instructions [here](http://samsungupdate.com/how-to/how-to-install-an-official-samsung-stock-firmware-using-odin).

For the latest firmware, you can look on [SamMobile](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/).

Comment: well at last that is what i m doing now.... :( nd luks like i cannot get a custom rom now.... tell me one more thing... cant i do flash a custom rom using ODIN..??

Comment: No you can't flash a rom using ODIN. The zip you download will have a factory image which contains all system files which ODIN flashes over your existing system. So if you an get a stock image somehow, it'll be easier to get your phone back up and running again.